# Border won't show despite appearing in inspect element

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating a small widget from a psd and trying to put a thin border-right between the 3 container divs I'm using to separate the page into thirds. The divs have height, and I've tried adding in forced height to ensure that isn't the problem, but for some reason it just won't show up. The CSS has CSS Reset at the start, which you can grab from [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Thanks for any help!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"><img src="1.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="txt">
    <div><p class="title taa">10</p><p class="title2 tab">,000 hrs</p></div>
    <div class="sub a"><p id="ac">Behavioural testing</p></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="img"><img src="2.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="txt">
    <div><p class="title tba">8</p><p class="title2 tbb">years</p></div>
    <div class="sub b"><p id="bc">Creafting successful user <br> experience since 2005</p></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="txt">
    <div><p class="title tca">87</p><p class="title2 tcb">years</p></div>
    <div class="sub c"><p id="cc">Collective experience</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="img"><img src="3.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border-right: 10px red;
}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.txt {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 91px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 57px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.a {
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to `border-right: 10px solid red;`

Border requires size and type of border; color is optional.

Comment: The amount of time I waste on these stupid mistakes recently is shameful. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, it happens. No problem.