# CSS border won't show on webpage, inspect element says "invalid property value"?

Tags: html, css

Found a similar question here

[Border won't show despite appearing in inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269932/border-wont-show-despite-appearing-in-inspect-element)

Answer is to change it from

`border: 20px solid red`

to

`border-right: 20px solid red`

Well that didnt do anything for me.

I tried top left bottom and right. Nothing showed.

```
body {
    border:20px solid #bdc3ct;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 80%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;

}
```

However, this works.

```
h2 {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border:20px solid red;
}
```

I can get a red border to show around my heading but I cant get a grey border to show around my body.

[Supposed to look like this. Everything contained within the border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB5ho.png)

[The border around the heading works, but no grey border. Inspect element shows in the bottom right corner "invalid property value"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naRcp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border color code is not working

```css
body {
    border:20px solid #333;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 80%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#bdc3ct
```

This is not a valid colour hex code.

Check this site for the correct hex value, or use RGB.

http://htmlcolorcodes.com/

Comment: Gotta love the small mistakes. ty

Answer (score 1):

`#bdc3ct` is not a color. Hex color values a 0-9 and a-f.

Chaning to `#bdc3cf` works

Answer (score 0):

I search in google and don't found color with code `#bdc3ct`.

use of other code, for example `#ccc`.

```css
body {
    border:20px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 80%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;

}
```

*One of best site for select color is*
[Here](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/)